# Demosaicing algorithm for constructing an image (received from a Bayer Filter Sensor) in Java from binary file

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio, demosaicing

I am supposed to construct an image in Java from a binary file that the Java Program reads. The file comes from a Bayer Filter sensor. The file consists of the binary values of each pixel .Every pixel is represented by 10 bits. A demosaicing algorithm is required to be written to build the image from the binary data.There are 1024*1280 pixels.Hence,1280*1024*10 = 13107200 bits = 1638400 bytes is the image size. Does anyone have such an algorithm implemented in Java ? I would be glad if someone could help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try breaking the task down into smaller tasks, and solve one at a time. For example, first solve how to read the 10 bits data (are they raw samples, or compressed in any way?). You probably want to store this as either 8 bits (`byte`) or 16 bit (`short`) samples (scale values up/down). Then, try to just read the image into a grayscale image (the intensities will not be linear, but at least you should recognize the image). Then implement the demosaicing to get the full color image. People have probably solved all or some of these tasks already, Google is your friend. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455257/how-to-convert-a-binary-image-data-to-a-jpg-file-in-java-where-every-10bits-in-t

Comment: post the source binary file and if you know also the configuration of the filter if not you need to try all combinations and select the correct one ... If you need full 30 bit color depth then use HDR or any higher color depth file format otherwise truncate to 24bit per pixel RGB ... Bitmap or what ever. Also see http://www.imatest.com/docs/raw/

Comment: @haraldK : The binary data comes from a camera sensor. Is it not that I have to first convert this binary file to a raw Bayer image ( for creating a raw Bayer image, do I need to use OpenCV Java interface ) and then apply demosaicing algorithm to get RGB for each pixel. And when I have it, I can simply use BufferedImage's setRGB function to create image?

Comment: Not sure why you would need OpenCV for this..? You could maybe use `BufferedImage.setRGB(...)`, but keep in mind that this uses 32 bit "packed" ARGB layout, giving only 8 bit/component. If your original data is 10 bits, you will lose some precision. Maybe not an issue for you? You will probably also have to do some color space conversion (`ColorConvertOp` will do that), to get your data in sRGB color space.

Comment: @haraldK: The binary file is in bayer pattern which means that each pixel is either red or green or blue. So, I think I cannot directly apply ´setRGB´ to the int array in which per cell I store every 10 bits. First from that binary file I need to create a Bayer pattern image which I think is possible only if I use interfaces like OpenCV or something else. So, I think after I create the Bayer image, I can apply demosaicing to get missing R/G/B values for each pixel and then may be use ´setRGB´. I am not sure if I should at all use OpenCV.

Comment: I know it's a Bayer pattern, you have mentioned that already. :-) But normally, the values from the sensor are stored as *intensities* rather than having a color. This is why I suggested displaying as a gray image, just to see if you have this part correct, before demosaicing.

Comment: @HeraldK. Thank you. Is there a gray scale equivalent for setRGB in Java. I have stored the file in a 1-D int[] array. And using the code :    BufferedImage bim=new BufferedImage(1024, 1280,     BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY); 
bim.setRGB(0, 0, 1024, 1280, pix, 0, 1024);
ImageIO.write(bim, "jpg", new File("path to /output.jpg"));   But sadly, this does not produce any output.

Comment: this question has come around several times- apperently it is of comercial high interest to you- why dont you pay someone to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using an external library.
There is a library called OpenCV which can be used for Java. The function Imgproc.demosaicing() converts a raw Bayer image to desired format.Thank you all for the help.